# Bash pwd for file in separate directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script to remove all files ending in `'~'` - as in temporary Emacs files.
My script is this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(ls -R)
do
if [ ${f: -1} == '~' ]
then rm $f
fi
done
```

This correctly locates all the files with that ending from the root directory. It works for any files in the current directory. The problem of course is that `rm` is only receiving the name of the file, not the full path, so it can't remove them.
Is there a way to get the path of a file at the time of listing it? If I run `pwd` in the script, it still only runs it from the current directory. I've seen advice about using `realpath` to get a full path, but that is also only for the current working directory. How do I save the path of a file in a temporary variable while running `ls -R`?

Comment: You don't want `ls -R`, you want `find`. Then you also don't need a loop because `find` can delete the files itself.

Comment: Also, take great care when testing command-lines to delete multiple files from a recursive directory search. Always test by printing out the matching files first, then convert to the delete form after you're sure it's not going to wipe everything.

Comment: I'm now using `find`. It works much better. The duplicate linked to at the top of this page has a great answer as well. Basically just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using `find` instead of a recursive `ls` may be the answer to your problem. `find` will effectively return the full path of the file along with the file name, so with this in hand you can iterate over them, check on whether they contain the character you're after and then delete them.

Comment: `find` also does the match for you, with `-name`, and the delete for you with `-delete`. Note the warning in the man page: -delete should come at the end, after -name has filtered down to only the matching files.

Comment: If I run `find *~`, I get `no such file or directory`. How do I pass an expression like this to `find`?

Comment: `find -name '*~'` does the trick. If I run `find -name '*~' -delete`, I think this will work. That's not going to wipe out the other files, right?

Comment: I tested it in a subdirectory after copying files elsewhere. 
Running `find -name '*~' -delete` works.